# Поиск файла в папке ресурсов

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources

Есть проект с архитектурой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке ресурсов находится файл `properties` и папка DB.

В папке DB есть файл properties.db.

Файл `properties` я нахожу просто:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties"));
```

А вот файл `properties.db` я найти не могу.

Что мне нужно прописать, чтобы найти `properties.db`?

Answer (score 0):

Так работает?

```
properties.load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("DB/properties.db"));
```

Comment: в том то и дело что нет

Comment: у меня работает. Вы не попутали регистр символов или имя файла?

Comment: Раскройте папку resources и перевыложите  скриншот

Comment: нет, не перепутал, если прокликивать путь к файлу через "ctrl" (нажать на контрл и кликнуть по пути к файлу) то мне открывается файл. Т.е. идея понимает к какому файлу я пытаюсь достучаться. Может проблема в том что у меня maven приложение на Spring-boot и он что-то изменяет в каталогах в ресурсах?

Comment: А так? properties.load(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/DB/properties.db"));

Comment: Так в Spring можно забирать данные с помощью @Value